# java Condition inside a loop

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
    System.out.print("Enter Number to Search: ");
    String get = br.readLine();
    int input = Integer.parseInt(get);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        num[i] = inFile.nextInt();
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if(input == num[j])
        {
            System.out.println("Search number is found!");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Search number is lost!");
        }

    }
```

the numbers inside num[i] are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

my problem is that when i try to search for number 5, the output is this:

```
    Enter Number to Search: 5
    Search number is lost!
    Search number is lost!
    Search number is lost!
    Search number is lost!
    Search number found!
```

how can i print the "search number found!" without printing the "Search number is lost!"??

Comment: Remove the `println`?

Answer (score 3):

Create a boolean expression and set it to false. Iterate through your loop, and if the number is found, set it to true and then print "Search number is found." After your loop ends, check if the boolean is false. If it is false, then print "Search number is lost!"

Answer (score 1):

Just lose the else statement in your second loop.

```
boolean found = false;
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if(input == num[j]) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(found)
   System.out.println("Search number is found!");
else
   System.out.println("Search number is lost!");
```

Comment: I believe he still desires to print number is lost if the number is indeed not found. A boolean as @jhobbie suggested will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Bascially I have removed the else statement from the for loop, and added a boolean flag to the if statement.  If the number is found, print out and set flag to true.  Once the loop has ended, check the flag to see if the number was found.  If not, print out.

```
    System.out.print("Enter Number to Search: ");
    boolean found = false;
    String get = br.readLine();
    int input = Integer.parseInt(get);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        num[i] = inFile.nextInt();
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        if(input == num[j])
        {
            System.out.println("Search number is found!");
            found = true;
            break;
        }    

    }
    if(!found){
        System.out.println("Search number is lost!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following piece of code which will clear the screen of all text before outputting number found / lost.

```
System.out.print("Enter Number to Search: ");
String get = br.readLine();
int input = Integer.parseInt(get);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    num[i] = inFile.nextInt();
}
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    if(input == num[j])
    {
        system("CLS");
        System.out.println("Search number is found!");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        system("CLS");
        System.out.println("Search number is lost!");
    }

}
```